# Comment are mix up when file is opened in windows/lunux

Tags: windows, linux, comments, porting

Hello
I have an application that should work in Windows and Linux.When I open(transfer) the file from one system to other my comments in code are mixed up .

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                              //
//                                              //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

And then I get something like this

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                      //
//                                          //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

What could be done?

Comment: you probably have tab characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the file through `expand -8`.  You have tab characters, which usually move to the next multiple of 8 characters but on some linuxes are set to do 4 characters.

```
expand -8 < foo.c > foo.c.new ; mv foo.c.new foo.c
```

should fix it.

Comment: could you elaborate  I pretty new to linux

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are tab characters in there and the editor on each system is configured to use different tab widths.  Make them use the same value, or use spaces instead, and your're golden.

Answer (score 1):

This will be because you've got tabs rather than spaces and the tab width will be different on the two machines.

You have two choices:

1. Make sure you convert tabs to spaces (it should be an option in your IDE).
2. Make sure the two systems have the same tab width (3 chars, 4 chars or whatever).